# Is this the fastest single digit sort algorithm possible?

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm trying to learn c++ and wrote this algorithm and I am wondering if there is a faster way to do the same thing. This is assuming that the input is valid. I was trying to think of how to remove the nested for loop but decided that it is fine since it is not exponential. Is this correct? Thanks

```
void DigitSort(int* arr, int size)
{
    int counts[10] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    int k = -1;
    while (++k < size)
        counts[arr[k]]++;
    k = -1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        for (int i = 0; i < counts[j]; ++i)
            arr[++k] = j;
}
```

Comment: the nested loop is still `O(N)` in total, you cannot get it better than `O(N)`

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: Note: you have an efficiency concern only if the size is much larger than 10. In such a case, one possibility is to stay with the `count[]` array as a particular representation of the sorted array.

Comment: I would use `std::size_t` for `counts` and indices. But apart from this, the code seems okay.

Comment: The sum can be computed in parallel using a reduce operation, although you'll only see a performance gain if the machine has segmented memory architecture.  The answer may be much different if you were targeting a GPU for example.  See: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Performance-Evaluation-of-Parallel-Count-Sort-using-Faujdar-Ghrera/0e2183d289dea9b4f0d6645b7c1f609f8f2d71f5

Comment: Although you have a large number of branches, many can likely be branch predicted. Instead of `int` `std::size_t` might be faster. However, if you want to be sure, create a small test environment and run your code against other implementations. See if you can outperform `std::sort` for different input sizes. Find other counting sort / bucket sort implementations and compare your code against those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benchmark, but here is a (probably) faster solution, using std::fill_n.

```
void DigitSort(int* arr, int size)
{
    int counts[10] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    int k = -1, sum_count = 0;
    while (++k < size)
        counts[arr[k]]++;
    
    for (k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
        std::fill_n(arr + sum_count, counts[k], k);
        sum_count += counts[k];
    }
}
```

When I say "probably", it's because the compiler can optimize the std::fill_n to a [memset-like](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) instruction.

Comment: I mean that I didn't make comparison tests on running times. By the way I just changed the code from memset to std:fill.

Comment: Why do you expect `std::fill` to be faster? (I'm not saying it isn't, but the answer might benefit from a rationale for that claim -- if no measurement is available).